# Detecting inconsistencies in a pandas string column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a usecase where all the columns of input dataframe would be str and we  need to detect outliers/inconsistencies.
For eg: 'A' : [32, 66, 45.7, 12, 19, inf, 90, 0.0, 22, 89, 21, 99]
'B' : ['1998-12-25, 1998-11-25, 25-10-1998, 25/09/1998, 08/25/1998, 1998-07-25, 1998-06-25]

In the column 'A', outliers would be [45.7, inf, 0.0] and as the column type should be 'int'
and In column'B' outliers would be [25-10-1998, 25/09/1998, 08/25/1998] as it is inconsistent with the majority of the data in that column.

Since the data would be huge, row-wise computation would not be ideal.

Is there a pandas lib to solve for this case?

Comment: Are you able to precisely define what you consider "(in)consistent"? If it's just the two cases you listed, then regexes can do simple string matching.

Answer (score 0):

Here below for both filters you can apply using lambda, to find the outliner you can check the elemnt type if its not int will consider as outliners

Code:

```
A = [32, 66, 45.7, 12, 19, 'inf', 90, 0.0, 22, 89, 21, 99]

outliers = list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, (int)), A))
```

Output:

```
[45.7, 'inf', 0.0]
```

Similarly, to find the different format dates simply define first the actual pattern and filter out the element the dates which does not following that pattern

```
import re

B =  ['1998-12-25', '1998-11-25', '25-10-1998', '25/09/1998', '08/25/1998', '1998-07-25', '1998-06-25']

pattern = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
inconsistent =list(filter(lambda x: not pattern.match(x), B))
```

Output:

```
['25-10-1998', '25/09/1998', '08/25/1998']
```

Comment: The question could be a bit clearer, but my guess would be that column `A`  is also a string column: _"all the columns of input dataframe would be str"_. But you could solve that part by using regex, too, I guess.